# Conda and pip are in different paths

Tags: python, macos, pip, conda, apple-m1

I installed miniforge on my Mac M1 and created an environment.

```
conda create --name myenv
conda activate myenv
```

In this environment, I installed python and pip. There are some packages specifically available on pip, so I did a `pip install -r requirements.txt`, assuming that these packages would be dumped in the myenv environment.

However, when I do `conda list`, I am getting only pip as the installed package and `pip list` is giving me all the installed packages.

When I checked the path, my conda environment is in this path -

> ~/miniforge3/envs/myenv/bin/python

while my pip is in

> /Users/I323017/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip

Could you please help me to create my pip env under the conda environment by default.

Comment: Looks like you didn't have the environment activated when `pip install` was called.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to fix the issue.

When I do just `pip install <package_name>` within my environment, the package still gets installed in

> /Users/I323017/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip

However, if I do `python -m pip install <package_name>` within my environment, the package will get installed under the environment directory.